# How are cyclodextrins used to form inclusion complexes with drug molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, drugs, medicinal-chemistry

I'm talking about practical application. A cyclodextrin molecule hosts a drug molecule inside of it in order to increase solubility and stability of the drug.

But how do we make sure this inclusion complex forms correctly? Is it as simple as mixing the drug along with a cyclodextrin in a solvent? Is it common for drug makers to include excess cyclodextrin (more than the 1:1 ratio needed) in order to ensure that all molecules of the drug are encapsulated in inclusion complexes?

Comment: There are books and plenty of reviews on cyclodextrins and their drug applications. Go to " Google Scholar" https://scholar.google.com/, and search this keywords.

Comment: Sounds like you read the title but not the questions.  Of course I've read papers on these things, but you'd be surprised at how many brush over the practical application.